# New to Java. Need help to understand testing for my function with some dependencies

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
@Autowired
private Publisher Publisher;

private int Id = 12345;
private BClient bClient = new BClient(Id);

private Map<Integer, Boolean> defaultBooleanValueMap;

private LoadCache<Integer, Boolean> booleanCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .refreshAfterWrite(refreshRate, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build(
                new CacheLoader<Integer, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean load(Integer id) throws Exception {
                        return fetchBooleanValue(id);
                    }
                }
        );
private boolean fetchBooleanValue(int id) {
    long fetchStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean val = bClient.getBoolean(id, defaultBooleanValueMap.get(id));
    publisher.publish(
            publisher.getDistributionMetric("fetchtime.bool", System.currentTimeMillis() - fetchStart));
    return val;
}
public boolean getBoolean(int id) {
    return booleanCache.getUnchecked(id);
}
```

//Trying to test getBoolean(int id) function. I'm mocking bClient, Publisher. Not sure how to properly test it

// Could anyone help me understand how to test it

```
//testing with
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(); 
@Mock 
Publisher publisher; 

@Mock
BClient bClient; 

@Test 
public void testGetBoolean(){ 
bClient = new BClient(12345); 
Map<Integer,Boolean> defaultBooleanValueMap = null; 
defaultBooleanValueMap.put(123, false); 
when(bClient.getBoolean(123,
defaultBooleanBregValueMap.get(123))).thenReturn(false); 
boolean b = someClass.getBoolean(123); 
assertFalse(b); 
}
```

// i'm don't know if i'm doing it right

Comment: Short summary:

Struggling to test a function(new to java overall). I have:

1. Private map<Interger, Boolean> contains data

2. Private function that fetches data from this map

3. Private object: uses object that calls func 2 to initialize itself

4. Function: calls a function within object 3 to get the data

Not sure which class I should mock. Could anyone suggest how should I go about it?

Comment: Can you provide your unit test? What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

    Mock
    Publisher publisher;
    Mock
    BClient bClient;

    Test
    public void testGetBoolean(){
        bClient = new BClient(12345);
        Map<Integer,Boolean> defaultBooleanValueMap = null;
        defaultBooleanValueMap.put(123, false);
        when(bClient.getBoolean(123, defaultBooleanBregValueMap.get(123))).thenReturn(false);
        boolean b = someClass.getBoolean(123);
        assertFalse(b);
    }

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right and concerned about "booleanCache" object.(removed @s)

Comment: Yeah as much as I love decryption you're going to want to put that in the original post in a code block.

Comment: Sorry, added to original

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Mockito?

It's good practice to not start a field name with a capital (Publisher for instance)

Personally i think it will be better to make all these methods protected instead of private, so that you can test each of them separately.

however this would be an example of a unit test for your code.

You can use Mockito to check if certain method calls are fired the amount of time you expect them to be fired.

I did not include all but you can just add if you need more tests.
Further i recommend to read about Mockito as it has some really powerful unit test tools

```
@Test
public void testGetBoolean () {
xxx.getBoolean

//the following line can only be done if you spy your service
Mockito.verify(xxx, times(1)).fetchBooleanValue(any());

//this line can be done if you mock bClient
     Mockito.verify(bClient , times(1)).getBoolean(any(), any()); //Mockito.any()  or you can fill in the real values if you really want.

//this line can be done if you mock Publisher
Mockito.verify(publisher, times(1)).publish(any); //again any or the real value you want to pass

}
```

I just now saw your unit tests, you can inject the mocks in you class with the following anotatation:
@InjectMocks
SomeClass someClass;

when mocking a class you don't manually have to create it again.

You don't have to mock the Bclient as you already create it with "new Bclient" instead of autowiring it.

I feel the @InjectMocks is not working because you didn't tell Spring that your class is a service component.

```
@Service
public class SomeClass {

//insert code here
}
```

Comment: @InjectMocks was not working and I deleted it temporarily. It seems I can't mock "bClient" because it's not an interface

I thought it would just work if I created an instance of SomeClass and called it's function

Comment: Did you mark your service with @Service or @Component?

Comment: I marked instance of a class.(I'm fairly new and don't know the difference) 
@InjectMocks SomeClass someClass;

Comment: I think before marking your class as a component or service, spring/mockito will not inject the mocks or autowire (also updated my original answer)